# Project level app admin role not able to execute project/environment CLI command in XM Cloud

Tags: xm-cloud

My team is currently working with `XM Cloud` where i have the organization admin role and my team member have the Admin access of a particular project app. I am able to execute all CLI command but when my team member trying to connect one of the environment under the project (on which, he has admin role), he is getting below error message.

[image]

Ideally it should work, as all developers can't have the organization level admin role. Any pointers?

Comment: is he able to perform dotnet sitecore cloud login command and then see the projects list using dotnet sitecore cloud project list command?

Comment: Have you raised a support ticket? This is not likely to be something that can be resolved on SSE.

Comment: Raman yes, he is able to login but can't access all project list because his role is app admin not org admin. Rechard, support ticket has been raised.